# Cannot get a WCF service to work in a third party hosting service

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, wcf

NB: This question requires more effort than just Googling for existing answers. I've done that. I think someone needs to be so kind to test the project on their own hosting service and find out what may cause this error.

I have created a WCF service that works fine when used on the development PC and on our internal IIS server. My problem is that the very same WCF service doesn't work when deployed on a hosting service (webhoster).

I know that I can find many related questions here and on other websites which discuss a similar problem, but I just cannot get it to work with all that info. I'm lost. Maybe I'm just overlooking something stupid/simple thing, but I'm now in a state that I just don't see it.

I have created a very simple test project, which you can download below if you want. This archive file also contains a Publish folder which contains the exact contents of what is hosted.

https://preview.cubbyusercontent.com/pl/TestService.7z/_785cfac455fe44b0820c1ed39cf7573b

I'm hosting this WCF service at a webhosting service, so I don't have direct access to IIS. The folder is set to be a application.

Again: The WCF service is working fine locally (on my development machine) AND also when deployed on our own IIS. I only have this problem error when deployed on an external hosting service!!!

NB: The language in this example is VB, but I also work with C#. So, it's ok if you provide an example in any language.

Currently the exact error message is as follows:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The type 'TestService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'TestService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: The type 'TestService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.]

System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +59206

System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1434

System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52

System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/xxxxxx/v1/Service1.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type 'TestService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found..]

System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +494824
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178 
System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult ar) +348350
System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +9549981

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18449
```

My very helpfull hosting service did implement the suggestions mentioned in the following links:

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45
http://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/publishing-a-wcf-service-on-iis8/

Unfortunately these additions didn't resolved the problem.

NB: Please don't just refer to general docs without explaining why my service doesn't work in a hosting service.

**Update 1:**
Based on the suggestion of Maxwell, I did a separate test with the following Service2.svc file (code in 1 file, not using the DLL):

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="TestService.Service2" %>

using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace TestService
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService2
  {
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
  }

  public class Service2 : IService2
  {
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
      return "You entered: " + value;
    }
  }
}
```

The web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">  
<baseAddressPrefixFilters> 
<add prefix="http://www.YourDomainName.com"/>  
</baseAddressPrefixFilters> 
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I now get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 21:       <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
Line 22:     </protocolMapping>
Line 23:    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">  
Line 24: <baseAddressPrefixFilters> 
Line 25: <add prefix="http://www.YourDomainName.com"/>  

Source File: \\192.168.0.100\localuser\plusserie\taskmanageronline\bpmlicense\v1\web.config    Line: 23 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18045
```

Comment: Have you verified that the markup in you're in .svc file matches what is in the configuration file?

Comment: @Tim What exactly do you mean?

Comment: If it works locally, you must be missing something from the deployed version. In the root folder for your deployed service, you should have a "svc" file. If you open this file in notepad, you will notice it is a pointer to the code-behind that is likely in your "bin" folder. Make sure this looks right.  Lastly, in your bin folder, make sure you have ALL (non .net) dlls required to make your application work. In other words, your dll for you service and stuff like dlls for your data classes, if you have them. Basically look at your local bin\Release folder and all dlls should be on the server.

Comment: I use the Build option in VS to create the build. I copy all those created files to the hosted environment. If I deploy the same build on our internal IIS server, then it works. I think it has to be caused by something like restrictions at the hosting provider (third party shared ASP service).

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility of a missing reference? See [this page](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/WCF_The_type_provided_as_the_Service_attribute_could_not_be_found.aspx) for description...

Comment: Please read my question.

Comment: based on your updated question regarding the web config error you are getting the <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"> is missing a close tag maybe edit it to <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it despite the vague error messages. I had put the web service in a subfolder of a parent folder that contained an other web service. That web.config conflicted with the web.config of my WCF service.

After I did place the WCF service in a root folder, the WCF service worked.

Comment: This can also work in a subfolder, but you will need to create an application context on it.  In IIS Manager, right click the directory and choose "Convert to Application."  You are correct as well that web.config inheritance can break your application.

Comment: The problem wasn't related to setting the folder to be a application; in my case this didn't matter for getting it to work. The one and only problem was the web.config inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, not really a direct solution to your question, but hopefully it helps towards finding the issue:

The exception you are receiving seems to be the result of not being able to find and load the type your service is implementing (obvious I suppose). Looking at the [reference code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel.Activation/System/ServiceModel/Activation/ServiceHostFactory.cs) (see the last method in the stacktrace), it seems to me, for some reason IIS is unable to load the `TestService.dll` file. Maybe permission issue, I can't tell, but here are couple of suggestions to help you hunt the problem:

First of all did you try to run service in-line as just an .svc file? Are you able to use this service, if you were to publish, or upload a this single .svc file?

**Service2.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="TestService.Service2" %>

using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace TestService
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService2
  {
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
  }

  public class Service2 : IService2
  {
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
      return "You entered: " + value;
    }
  }
}
```

Just browse to `/path/to/Service2.svc` and see if that worked (which hopefully would). This means that you are able to use WCF services on the target environment. If not, hopefully you have a different exception you can go to your provider with.

If that worked, now you can test if you are able to load your type from the DLL you are publishing. Again just use this in-line single file to test that:

**test.aspx**

```
<%@ Page language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Reflection"  %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web"  %>
<%
    var serviceType = "TestService.Service1";

    Type type = null;
    Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    for (int i = 0; i < assemblies.Length; i++)
    {
        type = assemblies[i].GetType(serviceType, false);
        if (type != null)
        {
            Response.Write("Found it! " + type.ToString());
            break;
        }
    }
    if (type == null)
    {
        Response.Write("Not found");
    }
%>
```

With this one, you will probably get a `Not found` result (as expected). At this point you are able to determine if your assembly is accessible or not. Try it with few other assemblies, compile your service code into a different assembly and upload that, and so on. The code above is pretty much taken from the reference code I mentioned above. That seems to be what WCF is trying to do and fail after not being able to find the service type.

More of a troubleshooting suggestion than an answer. I hope it helps.

Good luck!

Comment: These are certainly good suggestions. I will use them asap and let you know what I've found.

Comment: I used your first code suggestion and now getting a different, more logical, error. It not resulted in a working service, but maybe I'm closer to it. I've updated my question with the result. Maybe you have an other suggestion based on this new result?

Comment: @MikeB that seems to be only a config error. Could you try tweaking your web.config to get it working? Or you could copy the Service2.svc file in any working application e.g. wherever the original test applications is running.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can  do is change the below config  to false.
**aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"**

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Otherwise you can add  the below attribute  to your Service class.

Code fix in VB

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
```

**NB:** the below code is in C#

```
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
....
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem stays the same after I used you suggestion. Please know that I cannot use the serviceHostingEnvironment element on a hosted ASP server.

Comment: serviceHostingEnvironment is already there on your Web.Config of the downloaded code. And after changing this it worked for me with  your code.

Comment: Did you test in an hosted environment or local? As described in my question, the WCF service is working ok locally but not when hosted.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it more clear that the problem only occurs when hosted, *not* when using it local.

Comment: @MikeB How much access/permission do you have to your  hosted environment ?
Can you do RDP to your hosted Server ?

Comment: It's a shared webhosting service, so I don't have direct access to it. Just FTP access.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the cubby is down. Did you get your issue resolved? If not, make sure that the `TestService.Service1` type exists, and also check that the folder you are deploying to (folder marked as an application in IIS) has the ".svc" file that Steve was talking about. If you don't have that, you will probably have to add one.

Here is an example of what should be in your "service.svc" file.

```
<%@ServiceHost
  language="c#"
  Debug="true"
  Service="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService"%>
```

Also check out the [How to: Host a WCF Service in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766(v=vs.110).aspx) article on the MSDN.

Comment: I just checked the link and for me it's still working. Can you try again?

Comment: It shows the gray square with green page that has 2 chain links on it above with the download button below, and the direct link https://preview.cubbyusercontent.com/pl/TestService.7z/_785cfac455fe44b0820c1ed39cf7573b. It doesn't do anything when left clicking the square or button, and the direct link says page not found in chrome. Right click save as on either square or button tries to save the whole web page...

Comment: I've now changed the link to the file; can you try that one?

Comment: Alright, that link worked and it builds. I took the contents of the Publish folder and put them in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestService, created an application pool called TestServicePool, converted the TestService folder to an application in IIS, then opened chrome and pointed to http://localhost/TestService/Service1.svc and it gives me the "You have created a service." page. I can also connect to the service with WCF Test Client at `http://bd07.asiweb.com/TestService/Service1.svc` which is my computer name on our network, and it shows GetData and GetDataUsingDataContract.

Comment: Do you think it could actually be that the dll that contains the `TestService.Service1` type is blocked by webhoster? That's what immediately comes to mind, but I have zero experience in dealing with web hosting providers, so I'm not sure on their policies in regards to things like that.

Comment: Please read my question. I don't have this problem locally, only when hosted.

Comment: Yep, I did. Re-read my last comment on this answer. I asked whether dll files are blocked by your "webhoster" hosting service. Are you supposed to be hosting services with your account? Do they even allow you to host `dll` files? The reason you are getting the error message in your question is because the `TestService.Service1` type is not being found. Either the `dll` file is missing, or it might be blocked by your host.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm with your hosting provider that WCF Service Activation is turned on?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731053(v=vs.110).aspx  (have them change version for the appropriate version)

also here is a non command line way to do it - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blambert/archive/2009/02/13/enable-iis.aspx

Also try adding the activation's to your web.config file

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816902(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: According to my webhosting service, they have more customers that are running WCF services. So according to them everything should be ready from their side.

Comment: ok try adding activations explicitly in your config file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816902(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try using the ServiceModel registration tool  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012(v=vs.110).aspx